# How to hide the banner "This site is read only at the farm administrator's request" after putting SP site in read only mode?

Tags: 2013, powershell

Today, as per client requirement,I made one of the site collections in our production environment on SP 2013 in read only mode. After doing so, we are getting

> **This site is read only at the farm administrator's request**

banner at the top of the page.

Is there any PowerShell command to hide this banner from the page?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Use Css to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a div with `id="status_preview"` right under the starting `<body>` tag.

Execute `document.getElementById('status_preview'+'').style.display='none'` to hide it (try it in devconsole of your browser).

There are a lot of ways to do it in SP, the fast & dirty one is to modify your masterpage to include lines like:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">
function rndmjsfnctnm127548247() 
{
   document.getElementById('status_preview'+'').style.display='none';
   return false; 
}
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(somerandomjsfunctionname1231241, 'SP.js');
</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
```

*rndmjsfnctnm127548247 is completely random here - select you own*

There is no powershell command nor other way to prevent that div from being inserted